# Show the name of hit gameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, raycasting

I'm creating a project for my school and it was going pretty good until now. I've searched for an answer for nearly an hour and still couldn't find anything (wrong tags?).

The thing is that I want to show the name of the item that player is hitting with raycast. I tried this but sadly it's not working:

```
#pragma strict

var rayLength : int = 10;

private var inventory : Inventory;

private var guiShow : boolean = false;

var bush : GameObject;
var player : GameObject;

function Start()
{
    inventory = GameObject.Find("First Person Controller").GetComponent(Inventory);
}

function Update()
{
    var hit : RaycastHit;

    var forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);

    if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, forward, hit, rayLength))
    {
        if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Wood")
        {
            guiShow = true;

            if(Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
            {
                inventory.wood++;
                Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
                guiShow = false;
            }
        }       
        else if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Sticks")
        {
            guiShow = true;

            if(Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
            {
                inventory.stick++;
                Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
                guiShow = false;
            }
        }
        else if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "BushFull")
        {
            guiShow = true;
            bush = (hit.collider.gameObject);

            if(Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
            {
                inventory.berry += 5;
                bush.GetComponent(BushController).berriesTaken = true;
                guiShow = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            guiShow = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        guiShow = false;
    }
}

function OnGUI()
{
    if(guiShow == true)
    {
        GUI.Box(Rect(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 100, 25), "Pick up" + hit.collider.gameObject);
    }
}
```

If anyone knows answer - please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: please don't add tags in the title, and Unity's "JavaScript" isn't actually JavaScript but UnityScript

Comment: Oh, ok. Sorry - won't happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `hit.collider.name` to retrieve the gameObject's name. If that doesn't work (which I'm 99% sure it will), use `hit.collider.gameObject.name`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little tricky because maybe it would be a greater idea not to use the `OnGUI()` method. It's easier to call a custom method from update when the raycast hit the player.

One example of an easier implementation is the following:

```
function Update()
{
    var hit : RaycastHit;

    var forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);

    if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, forward, hit, rayLength))
    {
        Debug.Log (hit.collider.gameObject.name); //Shows the hittenGo in the console

        drawColliderName(hit.collider.gameObject.name);

        if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Woods")
        {
            //do Woods tuff
        }
        else if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Sticks")
        {
            //do Sticks stuff
        }
        else if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "BushFull")
        {
            //do BushFull stuff
        }
   }
}
```

Of course you have to implement the method `drawColliderName` where you must draw the Collider name on the GUI.

If you just want your code to work, in the `OnGUI()` you have to call name variable, like in the Debug.Log call of my code, this is just calling `hit.collider.gameObject.name` instead of `hit.collider.gameObject`